# Linq / Entity Framework logic

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Quite new to linq but i've got this

```
 public List<vwFolder> GetFoldersByUser(Guid UserId)
 {
     return 
         dc.vwFolders.Where((x => x.userid == UserId || x.userid == null) 
                             && x.deletionstatecode == 0)
                     .ToList();
 }
```

I'm trying to return records where:

userid is the userid I pass in OR null
deletion statecode = 0

There seems to be a syntax error in my code though, and not sure why.

Thanks

Comment: Check your parentheses.

Answer (score 5):

It looks to me that you just need to put the lambda outside your parenthesis. Try this:

```
public List<vwFolder> GetFoldersByUser(Guid UserId)
{
return dc.vwFolders.Where(x => (x.userid == UserId || x.userid == null) && x.deletionstatecode == 0).ToList();
}
```